# Larger .exe file cannot delete itself, while smaller one can with the same code (Delphi)

Tags: file, delphi, version, exe, shellexecute

I would like to write a program in Delphi, which deletes itself and copies another version instead of it, another .exe file with the same name from another folder. I tried this code on a testing project and it worked. But when I copied it for my larger project, it cannot delete itself.
Size of the large project is 68 413 KB (in case it has any connection with the problem..)

Any suggestions?

```
AppName:= ExtractFileName(ParamStr(0));
myBatFile:= 'copy.bat';
AssignFile(myText, myBatFile);
Rewrite(myText);
Writeln(myText, 'del ' + AppName);
Writeln(myText, 'copy whateverPath\myProgram.exe whateverPath\destination\myProgram.exe');
Writeln(myText, 'del ' + myBatFile);
CloseFile(myText);
ShellExecute(Application.Handle,'open','copy.bat',nil,nil,SW_ShowNormal);
Halt;
```

Comment: You cannot delete an executable that is currently running. You will have to find other means. One of it is to use the timeout batch command to wait for a certain amount of seconds which will give you time to quit the application before the batch file copies the new version. The other way is to write a separate exe which is called to do the copying after you have quit the app.

Comment: Thank you, yes I think, i'd better find other means. I tried waiting from the batch file but i think it's better to use separate batch or exe file. Thank you for attention

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot delete file of running process. But you can rename it!
So you can:

1. Download new executable into *.tmp file
2. Rename *.exe into *.exe.tmp
3. Rename downloaded file from *.tmp to *.exe
4. Restart application
5. Delete *.exe.tmp

Comment: I used the idea of renaming into *.tmp and it's perfect! thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 3):

When you call `ShellExecute` a new command interpreter process is created, process B. Then `ShellExecute` returns and your process, process A, continues to execute.

You now have what is known as a race. The two processes are in a race. Process B is trying to delete the excutable file used to create process A. So process A needs to terminate before process B completes in order for that to succeed. But you've not put anything in place to achieve that.

The correct way to achieve this is as follows:

1. Have a second executable file that will perform the copy and deletion. This will be process B.
2. Have process A create the new process B passing filenames as command line argument. And also passing an duplicated inheritable process handle for process A.
3. Once process A has done step 2 it terminates.
4. Process B now waits on the process handle provided in step 2. When that handle is signaled, process B knows that process A has terminated and the executable file can be deleted.

Answer (score 3):

You could use The Self-Deleting Batch File method from http://www.catch22.net/tuts/self-deleting-executables to delete your executable after it has exited and then copy new executable and delete batch file.

```
procedure UpdateMeAfterClose(const NewFilename: string);
var
  batch: TStrings;
  appName, newApp, batchName: string;
begin
  batch := TStringList.Create;
  try
    //** Get batch filename in temp
    batchName := TPath.GetTempPath;
    if GetTempFileName(PChar(batchName), 'bat', 0, PChar(batchName)) = 0 then
      RaiseLastOSError;
    batchName := ChangeFileExt(batchName, '.bat');
    newApp := AnsiQuotedStr(NewFilename, '"');
    appName := AnsiQuotedStr(Application.ExeName, '"');

    batch.Add(':Repeat');
    batch.Add('del ' + appName); // try to delete current exe
    batch.Add('if exist ' + appName + ' goto Repeat');
    batch.Add('copy ' + newApp + ' ' + appName); // copy new exe
    batch.Add(appName); // start new app
    batch.Add('del "' + batchName + '"'); // delete this batch file
    batch.SaveToFile(batchName);
  finally
    batch.Free;
  end;
  ShellExecute(0, 'open', PChar(batchName), nil, nil, SW_HIDE);
end;
```